# Why should we delete the memory allocated by new?

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

It is said that the memory allocated by `new` should be freed by `delete`, but a modern desktop OS will reclaim the memory even though you don't `delete` it. So why should we `delete` the memory allocated by new?

Also `assert` is known as not calling the destructors, and it seems like it's widely used in STL (at least VS2015 does that). If it's advised to `delete` the memory allocated by `new` (classes like `string`, `map` and `vector` use the destructor to delete the allocated memory), why the developers still use lots of `assert` then?

Comment: Because you don't want to run out of memory. If you're constantly allocating memory, but never deallocating any, then eventually you'll run out of it.

Comment: Usually the program is not meant to run any further after an assert happens, as it's meant for cases such as "oh fuck, this shouldn't ever ever happen (and if it does, we may as well stop execution)".

Comment: If the C++ program runs for a very short time, you can get away with skipping the delete calls. It will be much like running a Java program and be done before the first garbage collection kicks in.

Comment: Although beginners tend to program for the first time on a modern desktop, and are prone to believe development happens on no other platforms, there is a significant amount of development that happens on something other than a modern desktop OS.    Similarly, beginners tend to write small programs that don't run for a long time - which is a circumstance where memory management matters less - and there are real-world programs that run 24/7 and will cause catastrophe if they fail due to memory exhaustion.

Comment: @Peter: It doesn't need to be a desktop OS, though. I've never professionally worked with either a mobile device or a server machine that failed to reclaim memory after a process ends. That C++ compilers exist for systems that do not reclaim memory is true, of course, but I think it's a weak argument if you intend to convince a beginner why avoiding memory leaks is important.

Comment: @ChristianHackl - believe it or not, I'm not actually trying to convince anyone of this.   The question of whether memory should be managed or not comes down to requirements of the system.  Quite simply, it is very difficult to convince someone of a need for memory management unless they are actually working in a setting where it is a significant concern.

Answer (score 2):

> Why should we delete the memory allocated by new?

Because otherwise

1. the memory is leaked. Not leaking memory is absolutely crucial for long running software such as servers and daemons because the leaks will accumulate and consume all available memory.
2. the destructors of the objects will not be called. The logic of the program may depend on the destructors being called. Not calling some destructors may cause non-memory resources being leaked as well.

> Also assert is known as not calling the destructors

A failed assert terminates the entire process, so it doesn't really matter much whether the logic of the program remains consistent, nor whether memory or other resources are leaked since the process isn't going to reuse those resources anyway.

> and it seems like it's widely used in STL (at least VS2015 does that)

To be accurate, I don't think the standard library is specified to use the assert macro. The only situation where it could use it is if you have undefined behaviour. And if you have UB, then leaked memory is the least of your worries.

---

If you know that the destructor of the object is trivial, and you know that the object is used throughout the program (so, it's essentially a singleton), then it's quite safe to leak the object on purpose. This does have a drawback that it will be detected by a memory leak sanitizer that you would probably want to use to detect accidental memory leaks.

Comment: Good points about the destructors and about how using `assert` in library functions is the implementation's own business.

Comment: I have a question: what does UB mean?

Comment: And another question: "nor whether memory or other resources are leaked since the process isn't going to reuse those resources anyway", in my opinion, although the resources are no more used, but they still occupy some memory, so it should still be a "leak".

Comment: @CharlesDong UB is abbreviation of Undefined Behaviour (mentioned in the previous sentence). As for your second question, memory is no longer occupied since the memory that used to own the memory is terminated.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the sentence "the memory that used to own the memory is terminated"...

Comment: @CharlesDong: I suppose that was just a typo and it should be "the process that used to own the memory is terminated".

Comment: @CharlesDong Christian is correct, that was a typo :)

Answer (score 1):

> It is said that the memory allocated by `new` should be freed by
>   `delete`, but a modern desktop OS will reclaim the memory even though
>   you don't `delete` it. So why should we `delete` the memory allocated
>   by `new`?

Careful! The OS reclaims the memory only *after* your program has finished. This is *not* like garbage collection in Java or C#, which frees memory *while* the program is running.

If you don't `delete` (or more precisely, if you don't make sure that `delete` is called by resource-managing classes like `std::unique_ptr`, `std::string` or `std::vector`), then memory usage will continue to grow until you run out of memory.

Not to mention that destructors will not run, which matters if you have objects of types whose destructors perform more than just releasing memory.

> Also `assert` is known as not calling the destructors,

More precisely, `assert` causes the program to terminate in a way that destructors are not called, unless the corresponding translation unit was compiled with the `NDEBUG` preprocessor macro defined, in which case the `assert` does nothing.

> and it seems like it's widely used in STL (at least VS2015 does that).

Yes, the standard-library implementation of Visual C++ 2015 does that a lot. You should also use it liberally in your own code to detect bugs.

The C++ standard itself does not specify how and if `assert`s should appear in the implementation of a standard-library function. It does specify situations where the behaviour of the program is undefined; those often correspond to an `assert` in the library implementation (which makes sense, because if the behaviour is undefined anyway, then the implementation is free to do *anything*, so why not use that liberty in a useful way to give you bug detection?).

> If it's advised to `delete` the memory allocated by `new` (classes like
>   `string`, `map` and `vector` use the destructor to delete the allocated
>   memory), why the developers still use lots of `assert` then?

Because if an assertion fails, then you **want your program to terminate immediately** because you have detected a bug. If you have detected a bug, then your program is by definition in an unknown state. Allowing your program to continue in an unknown state by running destructors is possibly dangerous and may compromise system integrity and data consistency.

After all, as I said above, destructors may not only call `delete` a few times. Destructors close files, flush buffers, write into logs, close network connections, clear the screen, join on a thread or commit or rollback database transactions. Destructors can do a lot of things which can modify and possibly corrupt system resources.

Comment: So according to your answer: 1) To a small program (the memory is always enough) it's OK to not use `delete` and let the OS to reclaim the memory. 2) Don't worry about memory leaks when using `assert`. Is the above right?

Comment: 2.) is certainly correct. 1.) is not correct, however. Stop seeing `delete` as some kind of RAM manipulation tool. Destroying objects correctly is a matter of **program semantics**. I believe you are creating a false dichotomy; you almost never call `new` and `delete` yourself in modern C++. Both of them are instead **called for you** by resource-manager classes. By using those classes, you avoid memory leaks *and* get correct program semantics *and* have to write less code. In contrast, using a lot of `delete`s is usually an indicator that you have a potential leak or other problem somewhere.

Comment: I think I've understand - deleting memory is recommended (according to C++ Primer Plus 6). Although the OS will be likely to free the memory, it's a good habit to delete the memory on your own.

Comment: Also one further question: what does 'potential leak' mean?

Comment: @CharlesDong: Using `new` and `delete` correctly is so hard that you are very likely to make some mistakes that may cause leaks. Hence "potential leak". In contrast, using `std::vector` et al correctly is so easy that mistakes are very unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common pattern that applications - in the course of their execution -dynamically create objects that will not be used throughout the program execution. If an application creates a lot of such objects of temporary lifetime, it somehow has to manage memory in order not to run out of it. Note that memory is still limited, since operating systems usually do not assign all available memory to an application. Operating systems, especially those driving limited devices like mobile phones, may even kill applications once the produce a too high pressure on memory.

Hence, you should free the memory of those objects that are not used any more. And C++ offers [storage class specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) to make this handling easier. `automatic storage duration`, which is the default, deletes objects once they run out of scope (i.e. their enclosing block, e.g. the function in which they are defined, finishes). `static` objects remain until the end of normal program execution (if reached), and dynamically allocated objects remain until you call `delete`.

Note that - in no way - any object will survive the end of program execution, as the operating system will free the complete application memory. For normal program terminations, destructors of `static` objects will be called (but not for objects of dynamically created objects that have not been deleted before). For abnormal program terminations, like triggered by `assert`, `exit` or the operating system, no destructors are called; you can rather think of a program terminates because you turn off the power.

Comment: I have a further question: if a destructor not only frees memory, but also do other things (e.g. close files), will resource leaks be caused? For example: `std::ifstream fin("text.txt"); assert(false);` Since the destructor isn't called, text.txt will remain open and there's a resource leak. Is that true, or the OS will close the file correctly?

Comment: @CharlesDong: It depends on the OS. The C++ language itself does not specify those things. But you have made an important discovery here: memory leaks are only *one kind* of resource leak.

Comment: There is no guarantee - neither by the C++ language nor by other mechanisms - that particular code will be executed, ressources will be freed. Systems like databases or operating systems cover such things with proper recovery mechanisms (transaction logs etc.)

Comment: Final question: 'you can rather think of a program terminates because you turn off the power', if we really turn off the power during execution, and some memory is allocated by `new`, will it cause memory leak?

Comment: No. If the operating systems restarts, the complete memory will be available  again. Hence, no memory leaks, especially not spanning OS restarts.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't delete *You introduce a memory leak*. Each time this operator is invoked the process will waste some portion of its address space until it ultimately runs out of memory.

Comment: But it's said that the OS will reclaim the allocated memory, so there won't be any memory leak...

Comment: @CharlesDong: The OS reclaims the memory after the program ends. The leak exists and grows while the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

After your program finishes you do not need to care about memory leaks, so in principle this would be fine:

```
int main(){
    int* x = new int(1);
}
```

However, thats not how one usually uses memory. Often you need to allocate memory for something that you use only for a short time and then you want to free that memory when you dont need it anymore. Consider this example:

```
int main(){
    while ( someCondition ) {
        Foo* x = new Foo();
        doSomething(*x);
    }  // <- already here we do not need x anymore
}
```

That code will accumulate more and more memory for `x` even if all that is used is a single instance of `x`. Thats why one should free memory latest at the end of the scope where it is needed (once you left the scope you have no way to free it!). Because forgetting a `delete` isnt nice, one should make use of RAII whenever possible:

```
int main(){
    while ( someCondition ) {
        Foo x;
        doSomething(x);
    }  // <- memory for x is freed automatically
}
```